# Replace data in div Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to add new lines to the end of current. I think problem is here

```
 $("#main_content").append(data);
```

it take new data all html (html + css) and add to curent data what is already shown

Maybe is it possible to take only  from data ?

or replece data with new and put the current to the first position?

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num_messages = num_rows;
    var loaded_messages = 0;

    $("#more_button").click(function(){
        loaded_messages += 10;
        $.get(base_url + "twitterpagination/get_messages/" + loaded_messages, function(data){
        $("#main_content").append(data);

        });

        if(loaded_messages >= num_messages - 10)
        {
        $("#more_button").hide();
        //alert('hide');
        }
    });
})
```

**html**

```
<body>
<div id="main_content">
<?php
foreach($latest_messages as $message)
{
    echo $message->username . ' - ' . $message->message . '<br />';
}
?>
</div>
<div id="more_button">
more
</div>
</body>
```

**result**

```
        user - message 1
        user - message 2
        user - message 3
        user - message 4
        user - message 5
        user - message 6
        user - message 7
        user - message 8
        user - message 9
        user - message 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use jquery text

http://api.jquery.com/text/

This should do it.

Comment: do you mean append(data).text() ?

Comment: append(data) return me full html page. Still do not know how to get from (date) only id="main_content" ?

Comment: maybe you can give (write) a small example. Sorry for asking

Comment: @ViktorsGolubevs sure , let me understand your problem better

Comment: @Viktors , is that ajax call in your control?

Comment: yes. It is pagination "load more" like on twitter With 1) sql I get first 10 items and with twitterpagination/get_messages/ function I get ajax call for others. if I do alert(data); it return full HTML page with css and in <div id="main_content"></div> is new data from ajax call but no previous ...

Comment: @Viktors , when you make the ajax call , why are you returning html, you should return pure data like json object or some string , its better to return Json object notation , you should parse that at client side and print however you want

Comment: making $("#main_content").append(data) it add to current lines new lines with all html and it view like http://imm.io/fSEQ you can see it. Maybe you can help?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7345/discussion-between-kobe-and-viktors-golubevs)

Comment: as I understand there is no chance to take from data (html) a part of html with id. I tried to find in web but nothing (